# Testing a Normal C# Function with a Task Inside It

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task

I have a class which I did not write, and I need to test its private fields. (Not my choice.)

```
public static class ArrayPool<T>
{
    public static void Return(T[] array)
    {
        PushTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var bucketIndex = (int)Math.Log(array.Length, 2.0) - 6;
            Buckets[bucketIndex].Push(array);
        });
    }

    static ArrayPool()
    {
        Buckets = new List<ConcurrentStack<T[]>>(25);
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
            Buckets.Add(new ConcurrentStack<T[]>());
    }

    private static readonly List<ConcurrentStack<T[]>> Buckets;
    public static Task PushTask; // I added this field.
}
```

I wrote the following test for this class:

```
[TestClass]
public class ArrayPoolTesting
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ArrayPool_Return()
    {
        // Act
        ArrayPool<int>.Return(new int[268435456]);

        // Assert
        if (ArrayPool<int>.PushTask.Wait(100))
        {
            PrivateType pt = new PrivateType(typeof(ArrayPool<int>));
            var buckets = (List<ConcurrentStack<int[]>>)pt.GetStaticField("Buckets");
            Assert.AreEqual(25, buckets.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, buckets[22].Count); 
        }
    }
}
```

However, it fails every time. It throws a null reference exception in the if condition of the test, because `ArrayPool<int>.PushTask` is `null`. (Actually, it fails every time on my work computer. On my home computer, where I wrote this stripped down version, it works every time. But I have combed over the two programs, and I believe they are essentially the same.) I did not want to modify the original class, but I did add the public `PushTask` field in the hope of making the class testable.

I get why it is failing. It gets to the if condition in the test before the Task in the method can complete and assign its value to the `Task` field. It does not help to increase the `Wait` time.

- Is there some way to salvage this approach?
- Is there a better way to approach this problem?

I know from debugging that the `Return` method is working correctly, but I cannot test it because the assertions run before the `Task` field gets initialized.

Comment: Was the original `Return` method using a `Task` or did you add it?

Comment: The original was using a Task. I added the PushTask field and the assignment of the Task.Run return value to it.

Comment: Refactor the code if you can and go async all the way. or sync all the way. mixing them is just asking for trouble.

Comment: But in any case make the test async and await the task.

Comment: Just FYI to who ever wrote this method. ArrayPool is a very poor name for this. Additionally, you should be testing behaviour not implementation and internal state. Lastly, This entire class is iffy and not thread safe, and bound to be broken by someone in the future regardless of the tests

Answer (score 1):

## Simple

The simplest way seems be to make `Return` not to use `Task.Run`.

## Less simple

If that is not possible then the next best idea is to make `Return` an async method.

This should not change how the existing code interacts with the method because it was returning void. (BTW. This should change too and all callers should `await` it).

```
public static Task Return(T[] array)
{
   return Task.Run(() =>
   {
            ...
   });
}
```

Then you can just await it in the test.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ArrayPool_Return() <--- Added 'async Task'
{
   // Act
   await ArrayPool<int>.Return(new int[268435456]);

   // Assert
   PrivateType pt = new PrivateType(typeof(ArrayPool<int>));
   ...
```

Even if you stay with `PushTask` idea, you should still `await` it, rather than `Wait(100)`.

Finaly